# Groovy cannot run classpath

Tags: java, groovy, classpath

I have two files, a.groovy and b.groovy. The first one is a.groovy and I put it in folder abc.

```
package abc;class A {void p (){print("haha")}};
```

The second one is b.groovy. I put it in the root folder.

```
import abc.*; class B {void p(){new A().p()}}; new B().p();
```

My question is how to run b.groovy. I tried to call "groovy b.groovy -cp abc", but it stills can not run as it can not resolve class A.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The groovy command line utility is looking for a file named `A.groovy` to load your class.  Failing that, it'd look for a class named A in the classpath, but since A isn't compiled yet it won't find it.

Change the filename to A.groovy and it should work.  You shouldn't need the -cp flag in that case.